# Layer Stacking in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

Similar to layer stack feature in ERDAS what functionality is available in GRASS. I am aware of `r.composite`, but it can accept only 3 layers. To obtain a stack of more than 3 layers what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use r.patch instead (r.composite accepts only 3 layers since it is dealing with RGB maps).

Comment: Make sure you check on each layer's resolution and your current region settings before using either `r.composite` or `r.patch`.

Answer (score -1):

try    gdal_merge.py command  (  in qgis--rast menu)